# Docker - Multi-stage build with two windows image, python & a windows executable

Tags: python, windows, docker, dockerfile

I have 2 docker images

1. python
2. wrapper around a windows executable (written by colleague)

I want to dockerize some python scripts (luigi tasks) starting the executable (with Popen)

**This container is a WINDOWS contianer, NOT LINUX (to start the executable)**

Each of below works fine

#### Dockerfile for Image 1

```
FROM path/to/executable-image

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]

RUN Set-TimeZone -Id \"UTC\"
```

#### Dockerfile for Image 2

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED "1"
ENV PYTHONPATH "."
```

How should I merge these 2 Dockerfiles in one multi-stage build? My senior suggested any of below options

1. use python as base layer -- `FROM python:3.10 AS python`, then only copy essential files like `python.exe` with `COPY --from=python`
2. write my own python windows image

Still, I am struggling to understand any of these directions. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to write a multistaged docker file by referring to this ? 
https://earthly.dev/blog/docker-multistage/ Basically multistage docker file will have 2 From commands and you could implement the same using a multistage dockerfile

Comment: You probably cannot simply copy the linux installation of python into a windows image. So you probably have to build your own.

Comment: What is the nature of the executable? Why not copy the executable into the official Python image for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is installing Python 3 directly into your Windows image:

```
RUN powershell -Command [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; \  
  powershell -Command Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0.exe" -OutFile "c:/temp/python-3.7.0.exe"; \
  c:/temp/python-3.7.0.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0; \
  del c:/temp/python-3.7.0.exe;
```